# What's difference between Q.nfcall and Q.fcall?

Tags: javascript, node.js, q

I am new to node.js. I am trying to understand Q.nfcall.
I have the following Node.js code.

```
function mytest() {
  console.log('In mytest');
  return 'aaa';
}

Q.nfcall(mytest)
.then(
  function(value){
    console.log(value);
});
```

My expected output should be:

```
In mytest 
aaa
```

But the actual output is:

```
In mytest
```

After I changed Q.nfcall to Q.fcall in the code above, the output became what I expected:

```
In mytest 
aaa
```

Why's that? What's difference between Q.nfcall and Q.fcall? Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) documentation:

> If you're working with functions that make use of the Node.js callback
>   pattern, where callbacks are in the form of function(err, result), Q
>   provides a few useful utility functions for converting between them.
>   The most straightforward are probably Q.nfcall and Q.nfapply

What it means is that `nfcall()` expects Node-style `function(cb)` which calls `cb(error, result)`.
So when you write:

```
Q.nfcall(mytest)
.then(
  function(value){
    console.log(value);
});
```

`Q` expects that `mytest` calls passed callback with `(error, value)` and `Q` then calls your `next` callback with `value`.
So your code should look something like this(here is [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/uX1mgCqkfH6ujm9e9pyL?p=preview)):

```
function mytest(cb) {
  console.log('In mytest');
  cb(null, 'aaa');
}

Q.nfcall(mytest)
.then(
  function(value){
    console.log('value', value);
});
```

You can look into [nfcall() test cases](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/blob/v1/spec/q-spec.js) to go deeper how it should be used.

Comment: detailed answer, but doesn't appear to answer OP's question

Comment: and fcall? what is the difference between nfcall and fcall? My guess is that it is the signature and return type of the func it can use. I will need to look this up somewhere else it seems.

Comment: fcall will return a promise that will be fulfilled with the result of your function. This is a convenient way to use a function that is not promise aware in a promise chain.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is good but to address the difference:

- **nfapply** expects an **array** of arguments
- **nfcall** expects arguments provided **individually**

For Example:

```
Q.nfcall(FS.readFile, "foo.txt", "utf-8");
Q.nfapply(FS.readFile, ["foo.txt", "utf-8"]);
```

See https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#qnfapplynodefunc-args

Answer (score 2):

While the accepted answer is a good explanation of nfcall it's not the difference between fcall and nfcall.

Both methods return a promise.

fcall returns a promise that is resolved to the return value from the function it receives.

nfcall returns a promise that is resolved (or rejected) to the value of the result of the callback that the input function should receive when called.

e.g.

```
return Q.nfcall(FS.readFile, "foo.txt", "utf-8");
```

can be translated to the following code

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
    FS.readFile("foo.txt","utf-8",function(err, result){
        if (err)
        {
            reject(err);
            return err;
        }
        resolve(result);
    });
});
```

Where

```
return Q.fcall(function () {
    return 10;
});
```

can be translated to

```
return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{resolve(10);});
```